# Excel VBA - Loop through checkboxes inserted in a column and fill another column if checked

Tags: excel, vba

I need guidance with my code. I have added 2 checkboxes  ( OK & NOK ) in each cell of the column F using the code Below.

Wanted logic : If a checkbox  is checked then we put the currentusername in column G

I am struggling with the if clause as i need to loop on all the checkboxes of the column F when i don't know their names

### Following is the code i used to create the boxes

```
    'Save cell dimensions and coordinates of corresponding cell in column E to variables
    CLeft = Cells(cell, "Q").Left
    CTop = Cells(cell, "Q").Top
    CHeight = Cells(cell, "Q").Height
    CWidth = Cells(cell, "Q").Width
    Range("B1").Value = CWidth
    
    'Create checkbox based on dimension and coordinates data from variables

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select
    
    With Selection
        .Caption = "ok"
        .Value = xlOff
        .Display3DShading = False
     End With
     
     C2left = CLeft + CWidth / 2
    
     ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(C2left, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select
    With Selection
        .Caption = "nok"
        .Value = xlOff
        .Display3DShading = False
        
    End With
```

End If
Next cell

Comment: You don't need to know the name, you can use the position of the box.

Comment: Are you open for a more simple solution which doesn't use Form or ActiveX checkboxes?

Comment: How will a click trigger an action?

Comment: The UI is a little confusing - typically you'd use radio buttons for a binary choice of OK/notOK ....  With two checkboxes there are 3 states  - both off (undecided), OK, not OK.  Is that what you need, and how to prevent both boxes being checked?

Comment: @TimWilliams good points; even simpler (from a user perspective) might be to have a single button that toggles its label between "OK" and "Not OK".

Comment: @Joffan  - in that case just a single "OK" checkbox would also work.  However, in the OP's case both checkboxes "off" might also mean "not yet reviewed for OK/notOK" which might also be a required state.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Sub Create()
    
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B11").Cells
        With ws.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width / 2, c.Height)
            .Caption = "ok"
            .Value = xlOn
            .Display3DShading = False
            .Name = c.Row & "_ok"
            .OnAction = "OnCbClick"
        End With
        With ws.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left + c.Width / 2, c.Top, c.Width / 2, c.Height)
            .Caption = "nok"
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
            .Name = c.Row & "_nok"
            .OnAction = "OnCbClick"
        End With
    Next c
     
End Sub

Sub OnCbClick()
    
    Dim cb, ws As Worksheet, nm As String, cb2, arr
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    
    Debug.Print cb.Name
    
    'find the matching checkbox in the pair
    arr = Split(cb.Name, "_")
    nm = arr(0) & "_" & IIf(arr(1) = "ok", "nok", "ok")
    Set cb2 = ws.CheckBoxes(nm)
    
    'allow one or other checked, but not both
    If cb.Value = xlOn And cb2.Value = xlOn Then cb2.Value = xlOff
    
    'ws.Cells(CLng(arr(0)), "G") = "Hello"       'if checkbox positions are fixed
    
    ws.Cells(cb.TopLeftCell.Row, "G") = "Hello" 'if checkbox positions are *not* fixed
                                                '  eg might move due to inserted rows etc
    
End Sub
```